# Azure Search - Not Enough Partitions Responded Error

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Have been periodically getting the following error message from the Azure Search API.

> {"error":{"code":"","message":"Failed to execute query because not enough partitions responded (11 of 12 succeeded, required success ratio: 1)"}}

This looks to be an Azure issue from where I am sitting, but they are reporting nothing on their status page. Is there something else that could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a program manager with the Azure Search team.  Can you tell me if this  happens occasionally or often?  If this only happens occasionally, a 503 is an indication that your service is too busy and you need to retry. If this happens often, it can indicate that the load is too heavy and more replicas are needed.

If you would like we would be happy to look into this more if you would provide your service name.  If you prefer not to post this here, feel free to reach out to me directly at LiamCA [AT] microsoft [dot] com.

Liam

Comment: Hey Liam - spot on thanks, I've gone through a few of my logs and it appears I'm getting hit heavy quite from a bot or something - would explain the too busy. Any chance this could return a 429 and a little bit more relevant error message?

Comment: Hi Nagoh, Here is a page that has our status codes that might help a little (http://bit.ly/13ckQ4D).  Also, when your service is starting to get busy during mass updates you will typically first start getting 207 HTTP responses.  This means that some of your posted uploads were not applied and you can simply retry the upload.  When you start getting 503's as you are, this is an indication that the entire upload failed.  Typically people implement an exponential backoff when this happens.  i.e., if you get a 503, wait 1 second and apply, if it still fails wait 2 seconds, then 4, etc...